# Two posts in same div - WP loop

Tags: php, loop, query-posts, html

I would need the following in Wordpress:

```
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    <div id="post-1" class="post">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post-2" class="post">
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    <div id="post-3" class="post">
        <h1>Title 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post-4" class="post">
        <h1>Title 4</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know how to get posts with WP loop, but how can I wrap every two posts in .posts-wrapped div?

I fetch the posts with WP_Query.

Thanks!

EDIT:
So I tried few ways to do it. For example with this:

```
$index=0;
<div class="posts-wrapped">

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $index++;   
?>
<div class="post">
        <h1><?php the_post(); ?></h1>
    </div> <?php
if(($index % 2) ==0){
echo '</div><div class="posts-wrapped">';
}
} ?>

</div>
```

But this prints one extra empty posts-wrapped div:

```
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    Lorem ipsum 1<br>
    Lorem 2 ipsum est<br>
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
    Lorem ipsum 1<br>
    Lorem 2 ipsum est<br>
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
</div>
```

How can i get rid of this last empty div? It screws my carousel (this content is part of carousel).

Comment: What do you mean? I have @dianuj solution but it quite not work.

Comment: [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, I researched and like I said I have tried it solving but with no luck. So why that attack?

Comment: Attack? You've got to be joking? It was a question and a link to part of the site FAQ, and you still have not posted the relevant PHP showing _what_ you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a matter of logic. You need to conditionally print the `div` markup. The counter in `$wp_query` will let you chose every second post.

```
if (have_posts()) {
  echo '<div class="posts-wrapped">';
    while (have_posts()) {

      the_post();

      if (0 !== $wp_query->current_post 
        && 0 === $wp_query->current_post%2
      ) {
        echo $wp_query->current_post.'</div><div class="posts-wrapped">';
      }

      the_title(); echo '<br />';
    }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: It prints one empty posts-wrapped div in the end always :/

Comment: @wpneebie : see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Get the index that counts the loop iteration and check the modulus operation to know that its even or odd

```
$index=0;
<div class="posts-wrapped">

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $index++;   
  ?>
<div class="post">
        <h1><?php the_post(); ?></h1>
    </div> 
<?php
if(($index % 2) ==0){
echo '</div><div class="posts-wrapped">';
}


        } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, it wraps all posts to posts-wrapped div now, so it doesn't quite work as it should.

Comment: Above code will wrap every two posts in  `posts-wrapped` div as you can see the `if(($index % 2) ==0)` condition is true then will close the previous div and opens the new `posts-wrapped` div

Comment: <div class="posts-wrapped">
 <div class="post">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum 1</h1>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
 <div class="post">
        <h1>Lorem 2 ipsum est</h1>
    </div> 
 <div class="post">
        <h1>Lore 3</h1>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="posts-wrapped">
</div>

This is what it posts. So it creates empty wrapper and first wrapper has only one.

Comment: See my updated answer put the `$index++` in the start of loop

Comment: Now it posts two posts in to correct wrapper div but it still create one extra and empty <div class="posts-wrapped"></div> in the end.

Comment: You need to take the count of total posts first and then in if add one more condition with `&& $index < $totalpost`

Comment: Should I add that condition to the if index  % 2 clause? Nope, doesnt work. Now it prints all posts to posts-wrapped" div

Answer (score -1):

Same problem, I pulled out my hair but i used a small jquery trick and i change the last element class name and it worked...

```
$('.parentdiv>div:last-child').removeClass( "posts-wrapped noClass" ).addClass( "nothing" );
```

Answer (score -1):

To wrap every two posts in a `.posts-wrapped` div, you can use the modulus operator `%` in your code to check if the current post is the second post in a pair. If it is, you can close the current `.posts-wrapped` div and start a new one before displaying the post.

Here's an example of how you might modify your code to do this:

```
<?php
$index = 0;

// Start the first posts-wrapped div
echo '<div class="posts-wrapped">';

// Loop through the posts
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $index++;

    // Close the current posts-wrapped div and start a new one if this is the second post in a pair
    if ( $index % 2 == 0 ) {
        echo '</div><div class="posts-wrapped">';
    }
?>
    <div id="post-<?php echo $index; ?>" class="post">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php
}

// Close the last posts-wrapped div
echo '</div>';
?>
```

This code will output the posts in pairs, with each pair of posts being wrapped in a `.posts-wrapped` div. The divs will be closed and opened at the appropriate times to ensure that there are no extra empty divs.