# Adding div after every two post on main loop! Why will first post not get counted?

Tags: loop, query-posts, html

So I am trying to add a div after every two posts in home.php and I almost followed the answer found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112753/two-posts-in-same-div-wp-loop) but changed it a bit to function with the rest of the theme. Now the problem is that in the first div that is hardcoded there are three posts, not two. I believe the problem is in how the posts are counted, but not 100% sure. Would love to get some pointer if there is anything wrong in the way I count posts or if the problem is somewhere else.
Here is my home.php

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header-home'); ?>

<?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
<div class="alert alert-warning">
<?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'roots'); ?>
</div>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="center-row"><!--not dynamic-->
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_format()); ?>
<?php if ( 0 !== $wp_query->current_post 
    && 0 == $wp_query->current_post%2
 ) {
    echo '</div><div class="center-row">';
 } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--last row-->

<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
<nav class="post-nav">
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('&larr; Older posts', 'roots')); ?></li>
  <li class="next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer posts &rarr;', 'roots')); ?></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first post doesn't get counted because you have this in your if statement:

`0 !== $wp_query->current_post`

According to [The Codex on WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> (available during The Loop) **Index** of the post currently being
>   displayed.

Being an index of the array, arrays always start off at 0 as it's first item. So by having that in your if statement, you are skipping the first post. To make this effective you would actually have to +1 to current post index THEN get the modulus, otherwise it will still skip the first post:

`( $wp_query->current_post + 1 ) % 2`

Hopefully that works!

Comment: To confirm this from the source: `current_post` [defaults to `-1`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3495), so when it is [incremented by `next_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3474) in [`the_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3505), the first post will be `0`.

Comment: This is great and makes sense. The only problem is that it adds an extra, empty div at the end of the page. I have been playing around with a few different ways to hinder this, but have not found a solution yet.

Comment: @StenW You can use `$wp_query->found_posts` which will tell you how many posts there are.